# ActiveMQ network subscription issue

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a strange behavior in ActiveMQ with network connectors. Here is the setup:

- Broker A listening for connections via a nio transport connector on 61616
- Broker B establishing a duplex connection to broker A
- A producer on A sends messages to a known queue, say q1
- A consumer on B subscribes to the queue q1

I can clearly see that the duplex connection is established but the consumer on B doesn't receive any message.

On jconsole I can see that the broker A is sending messages, up to the value of the prefetch limit (1000 messages) to the network consumer, which seems fine. The "DispatchedQueue", "DispatchedQueueSize", and more importantly the **"MessageCountAwaitingAck"** counters have the same value: they are **stuck to 1000**.

On the broker B, the queue size is 0.

At the system level, I can clearly see an established connection between broker A and broker B:

```
# On broker A (192.168.x.x)
$ netstat -t -p -n
tcp    89984 135488 192.168.x.x:61616 172.31.x.x:57270 ESTABLISHED 18591/java

# On broker B (172.31.x.x)
$ netstat -t -p -n
tcp    102604 101144 172.31.x.x:57270 192.168.x.x:61616 ESTABLISHED 32455/java
```

Weird thing: the recv-q and send-q on both brokers A and B seem to have some data not read by the other side. They don't increase or decrease, they are just stuck to these values.

The ActiveMQ logs on both sides don't say much, even in TRACE level.

Seems like **neither broker A or broker B are sending acks for the messages to the other side**.

How is that possible? What's a potential cause and fix?

**EDIT**: I should add that I'm using an embedded ActiveMQ 5.13.4 on both sides.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see consumers on A or B? Which consumer has DispatchedQueue with 1000 messages?

Comment: There is a network consumer on A due to the the presence of a network subscription from B. The values I mentioned are on the consumer on A.